# Retrieving and Sending Objects using Parse Server

Tags: android, parse-server

I am using the Parse Server back-end with android studio and have read its developer guide; however, I'm still not totally getting it, specifically with retrieving objects. If someone could help clearing or provide a link to a good tutorial it would be great.(I learn the best through examples). I have searched YouTube and most tutorials aren't very good or only cover minimal topics on using parse. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can find an excellent android developer guide in here:

http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/android/guide/

During the past years i read a lot of docs from other vendor and Parse have the best docs that i ever see. There docs contain explanations with a lot of code snippets .

Comment: That's where I looked, Thank you though, I guess I just need to put in more time even though I've read it through multiple times. If you find any more sources please let me know. I'll mark your answer as correct. @Ran Hassid

Comment: All the resources that you need can be found under the URL that i specified in the answer and also in StackOverflow